# Proving that $L^1(X,M,\mu)$ is not reflexive

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, weak-topology

> Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space s.t there exists an infinite sequence of disjoints measurable sets of strictly positive finite measure. Show that $L^1(X,M,\mu)$ is not reflexive.

My attempt: this question followed a question that asked to prove that a TVS $V$ is reflexive $\iff$ the closed unit ball in $V$ is weakly compact. I tried showing that $\{f\in L^1:\|f\|_1\leq1\}$ is not weakly compact, but I wasn't able to find an open covering by weak open sets s.t it has no finite subcovering. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the assumption?

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, I considered $\chi_{E_i}$ for each $i\in I$. Those are in $L^1$ and $\|\chi_{E_i}-\chi_{E_j}\|=\mu(E_i)+\mu(E_j)$, so it's easy to construct an open covering that has no finite subcover and show that the unit ball is not compact in the regular topology. I wasn't able to show that it's not weakly compact

Comment: $\chi_{E_i}$ needs not in $L^1$ unless $\mu(E_i)<\infty$.

Comment: Correct, guess I assumed they were of finite measure

Comment: The statement is wrong . If $\mu (A)=\infty$ for every non-empty set $A$ then $L^{1}=\{0\}$ is reflexive.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Fixed it

Comment: Since a closed subspace of a reflexive Banach space is reflexive, it suffices to show that the closure of the linear span of $\{\chi_{E_i} : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not reflexive. This should be pretty similar to the usual proof that $\ell^1$ is not reflexive. My hunch is that those two spaces are actually isomorphic. It's worth keeping in mind that you have to use something like Hahn-Banach to prove this. In axiomatic systems without Hahn-Banach, this can be false. See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5351/whats-an-example-of-a-space-that-needs-the-hahn-banach-theorem/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll turn my comment into an answer. Suppose that $E_i$ are pairwise disjoint sets which satisfy $\mu(E_i)\in (0,\infty)$ for all $i$ and call $e_i = \mu(E_i)^{-1} \chi_{E_i}$, where $\chi$ denotes the indicator function of a set.

By the [Eberlein-Smulian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem), sequential weak compactness is the same as weak compactness for Banach spaces, so it suffices to argue that the sequence $(e_i : i =1,\dots)$, which lie in the unit ball of $L^1(X,M,\mu)$, cannot have a weakly convergent subsequence. Suppose that a subsequence $e_{n_k}$ converges weakly to some $\tilde{e}$ and define
$$
g = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k e_{n_k}.
$$
Notice that because the $E_i$ are pairwise disjoint, $\|g\|_{L^\infty(X,M,\mu)} = 1.$ Define a bounded linear functional on $L^1(X,M,\mu)$ by
$$
\Lambda(f) = \int_{X} g f d\mu
$$
so that $|\Lambda(f)| \leq \|f\|_{L^1(X,M,\mu)}$. By construction, we have $\Lambda(e_{n_k}) = (-1)^k$, which does not converge, a contradiction.